# SwiftyJSON YouTube API

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am using SwiftyJSON to retrieve data from the youtube api.
I am writing swift 4 code.

I'm trying to print out the description

Here is what I have:

```
func getFeedVideos() {
    Alamofire.request(API_URL, method: .get, parameters: ["part":"snippet", "playlistId":PLAYLIST_ID,"key":API_KEY], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

        if let value = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(value)

            print(json["items"]["snippet"]["description"].stringValue)
        }

    }
}
```

But no description is being printed out.

Below is the youtube API:

```
  "items" : [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
      "etag": etag,
      "id": string,
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": datetime,
        "channelId": string,
        "title": string,
        "description": string,
        "thumbnails": {
          (key): {
            "url": string,
            "width": unsigned integer,
            "height": unsigned integer
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": string,
        "playlistId": string,
        "position": unsigned integer,
        "resourceId": {
          "kind": string,
          "videoId": string,
        }
      },
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at the first line of the response, you'll notice the following:

> `"items" : [`

The `[` indicates `items` is an array, which means you should try

> `items[0]["snippet"]["description"].stringValue`

Comment: How would I print out all the descriptions for all the items?

Comment: I would first pull out items into an array of dictionaries (think `[[String: Any]]`), then iterate over that array, accessing each item's description with `["snippet"]["description"]`.